# What choice of Kohen did a person bringing a korban have?

Tags: kohen-priest, korban

I recently asked a question about a Kohen's responsibility for negligent disqualification of a Korban. The first answer I saw indicated that a Kohen is liable only for intentional disqualification (this may not be the correct answer, but let's assume for the purposes of argument that it is).

Let's say everyone knows a Kohen is negligent and keeps making mistakes. Can people refuse to give that Kohen their Korban and ask for a different one?